# How to implement a simple native Drag and Drop?

Tags: javascript, drag-and-drop

I'm trying to implement a simple drag and drop effect on a div. I'm using the native HTML5 API. Basically, I'm trying to drag the left pink box to the dark gray area. See the fiddle: All seems to be ok, however, I'm not able to drop the box in the dark gray area.

https://jsfiddle.net/pablodarde/2wy1s2vn/

I'm using this [documentation](https://www.sitepoint.com/html5-native-drag-and-drop-api/) as support.

This is my code:

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="side-bar">
    <div class="box" draggable='true'></div>
  </div>
  <div class="drop-zone"></div>
</div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
const box = document.querySelector('.box');
const dropZone = document.querySelector('.drop-zone');

const handleDragStart = (e) => {
    console.log(e.dataTransfer);
  e.dataTransfer.effectAllowed = 'move';
};

const handleDragEnter = (e) => {
    e.target.className += ' active-drop';
  e.dataTransfer.dropEffect = 'move';
  console.log(e.dataTransfer);
  e.preventDefault();
  e.stopPropagation();
}

const handleDragLeave = (e) => {
  e.target.className = 'drop-zone';
}

const handleDrop = (e) => {
    console.log('Drop!!');
  e.preventDefault();
  e.stopPropagation();
}

box.addEventListener('dragstart', handleDragStart);

box.addEventListener('drop', handleDrop);

dropZone.addEventListener('dragenter', handleDragEnter);

dropZone.addEventListener('dragleave', handleDragLeave);
```

Comment: What's wrong with your current implementation? I.e. what is your question?

Comment: Hi @Teemu, I edited my question. All seems to be ok, however, I'm not able to drop the box in the dark gray area.

Comment: Hi @RutwickGangurde, yes, it is. The box has the `draggable='true'` attribute.

Comment: Yes, my bad, it works on Chrome, not on FF ES version.

Comment: There seems to be a trusting problem in FF, "Error: Permission denied to access property "target" ".

Comment: Yes, I'm trying on Chrome for now, but I'll need to solve this on firefox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following 4 things should solve your browser/event related issues and handle the drop for you:

1. The `drop` event has to be attached to the `dropZone` div.
2. Cancel the event in the `dragover` event handler. You don't have one, add it.

For Firefox:

3. Add the following line to your `dragstart` handler:

   ```
   e.dataTransfer.setData('sourceId', '<id of the source>');
   ```

This could be any ***key-value***, but it **has to be** set for drag drop to work in Firefox. I have set the ID of the box since I want to use it in the drop handler.

4. Drop handled to append the box to the dropzone: https://jsfiddle.net/kyqr1o6b/3/

**Final working code with the drop handled**: https://jsfiddle.net/kyqr1o6b/6/

**Update**: Added support for Firefox.

**Update 2**: Drop handled.

**Update 3**: Positions captured.

Comment: Thanks, friend, but, although I can trigger the "drop" event with your code, I can't drop the box in the drop zone.

Comment: Hey! For that you will have to write the logic/code, friend. :) Btw, I have added support for Firefox as well.

Comment: Really? Should I need to catch the drop position, remove the original box and add a new box in the captured position? I thought that the drop method would do it for me.

Comment: I am not sure about the HTML5 drag and drop, but I am well aware of the drag/drop implemented using mousedown-move-up sequence, and it requires you to write the logic for position manipulation.

Comment: Ok, I will try to write the logic.

Comment: I have updated the code for the solution, you can just clean it up a bit. Check my updated answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154706/discussion-between-rutwick-gangurde-and-pablo-darde).

Answer (score 0):

Although I accepted the above answer, I'm leaving here an option with React. I found out how to explore React state feature to easily build a simple drag and drop solution

Codepen
https://codepen.io/pablodarde/pen/gGoQYo

**JavaScript**

```
class Square extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      posx: 10,
      posy: 10,
    };
    this.setDrag = this.setDrag.bind(this);
    this.startDrag = this.startDrag.bind(this);
    this.stopDrag = this.stopDrag.bind(this);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.sq.addEventListener('mousedown', this.setDrag);
  }

  startDrag(e) {
    console.log('posx: ', this.state.posx);
    console.log('startPosX: ', this.startPosX);
    this.setState({
      posx: parseInt(e.clientX - this.startPosX, 10),
      posy: parseInt(e.clientY - this.startPosY, 10),
    });
    this.startPosX = e.clientX - this.state.posx;
    this.startPosY = e.clientY - this.state.posy;
  }

  stopDrag() {
    document.documentElement.removeEventListener('mousemove', this.startDrag);
    document.documentElement.removeEventListener('mouseup', this.stopDrag);
    this.sq.addEventListener('mousedown', this.setDrag);
  }

  setDrag(e) {
    console.log('mouse down');
    this.sq.removeEventListener('mousedown', this.setDrag);
    this.startPosX = e.clientX - this.state.posx;
    this.startPosY = e.clientY - this.state.posy;
    document.documentElement.addEventListener('mousemove', this.startDrag);
    document.documentElement.addEventListener('mouseup', this.stopDrag);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div
        className='square'
        style={{
          left: this.state.posx,
          top: this.state.posy,
        }}
        ref={(sq) => { this.sq = sq; }}
      >
        {this.state.posx}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Square />,
  document.getElementById('app')
);
```

**CSS**

```
.square {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: #900;
  border: 1px solid #333;
}
```

Comment: As far as React goes, I have also had personal success with the [React-DnD](https://github.com/react-dnd/react-dnd) library.

Comment: Yes, I've seen the React-DnD before. However, for my purposes, the class above was enough and wasn't needed import the entire library. Thanks, @223seneca.